# Valid binding root for VSS?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I'm trying to fix up my Visual Source Safe bindings for a project I have and when I select the location I believe a project should be bound to, i get a dialog that says:

`The folder you chose is not a valid binding root for the projects you have selected. You attempted to retarget a solution to a source control folder that is not within the solution's root. In the change source control dialog box, specify the root for the solution. Select the folder 5 levels higher in the tree to chagne the source control bindings correctly.`

What on earth does that mean? There are no folders 5 levels higher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I figured this one out. I opened my vcproj file and searched for ..\..\.. and found a couple of references to files 5 directories "higher". I removed those references (the files weren't really there) and reopened the project. After doing this, I could rebind the project to SourceSafe.

Comment: Thanks for this, you just helped me figure out my problem!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check that the local version of the file "(project name).vspscc" is the latest one. It solved the problem in my context.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same basic issue, with VSS asking me to select a directory two levels higher than the one I had selected.

Editing the .vcproj file in Notepad, I found "SccLocalPath=..\..", and references to two files (both of which should have been removed from the project) located in "..\.." relative-path directories.  I manually removed those two files from the .vcproj and changed SccLocalPath to simply "..", problem solved.