# Visual Studio 2013 VSS binding error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

When I click on the "Change Source Control..." menu item, all projects in my Solution are Bound except for the Deployment Project.  When I attempt to bind the Deployment project, I get this error message:

> The folder you chose is not a valid binding root for the projects you have selected. You attempted to retarget a solution to a source control folder that is not within the solution's root. In the change source control dialog box, specify the root for the solution. Select the folder 5 levels higher in the tree to change the source control bindings correctly.

The fixes mentioned in this answer don't apply to me as I don't have any "..\" in the .vdproj file...

[Valid binding root for VSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448350/valid-binding-root-for-vss)

The Deployment project is in a subfolder of the .sln folder.

How can I get around this error message?

Answer (score 0):

You may try below steps and see if it works.

1. Back up your solution
2. Unbind the solution and projects in Change Source Control dialog.
3. Save and restart visual studio.
4. Try rebinding the projects to VSS.